# Deciphering Heroku 'git push' output from regluar 'git push' output errors

Tags: git, parsing, heroku, push, stderr

Currently I parse STDERR output from  `git push -q` to present any `git push` errors to the user. This works wonderfully most of the time. However when pushing to Heroku, their pre-receive hook outputs the status of the server and application status to STDERR as well.

I am basically just looking for an easy way to differentiate whether the output is actually errors from git vs extraneous Heroku data. I've tried checking for the presence of a "`---->`" prefix, but not all Heroku output has it. I also thought of checking for "`fatal:`" and "`ssh:`" in the STDERR string, but that seems very brittle. And I couldn't find any documentation that every git error is prefixed with `***:`

Actual Git Error sent to STDERR:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname heroku.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Typical Heroku Status:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rack app detected
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.3
       All dependencies are satisfied
       Compiled slug size is 8.4MB
-----> Launching.... done
       http://XXXXXXX.com deployed to Heroku
```

Does anyone have any ideas of a better way to accomplish identifying only the real git errors?

Comment: I know I can look at the exit status to tell whether the push succeeded, but I want to present meaningful error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Heroku: as of right now, there is no bullet-proof way to differentiate Heroku output from Git output. But they are working on standardizing their output format.

So it's mostly a matter of looking for the most common elements.